# Which Route gets executed in Laravel 5 http://localhost:8000/my/8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Given the resource controller below which one gets executed when entering http://localhost:8000/my/8?  When I tried it all I get is blank. The other routes like index and create? How does Laravel decide which route to execute in http://localhost:8000/my/8?

```
Route::resource('my','myController');
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class MyController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        echo 'index';
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        echo 'create';
        //
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        echo 'show';
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        echo 'edit';
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
        echo 'destroy';
    }
}
```

Routes:

```
    | POST                           | my                                                 | my.store   | App\Http\Controllers\myController@store            |            |
|        | GET|HEAD                       | my                                                 | my.index   | App\Http\Controllers\myController@index            |            |
|        | GET|HEAD                       | my/create                                          | my.create  | App\Http\Controllers\myController@create           |            |
|        | DELETE                         | my/{my}                                            | my.destroy | App\Http\Controllers\myController@destroy          |            |
|        | PUT|PATCH                      | my/{my}                                            | my.update  | App\Http\Controllers\myController@update           |            |
|        | GET|HEAD                       | my/{my}                                            | my.show    | App\Http\Controllers\myController@show             |            |
|        | GET|HEAD                       | my/{my}/edit                                       | my.edit    | App\Http\Controllers\myController@edit
```

Comment: Please, post your routes.

Comment: I updated my post containing routes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've already set your route resources, laravel should execute:

```
Route::get('my/{id}', 'myController@show'); // This will be called. 

public function show($id)
{
        echo 'show';
        //
 }
```

If you run this command

```
php artisan routes:list
```

you can see all your application routes and the corresponding actions.

Laravel chooses appropriate Controller methods based on the request type.

If you are visiting a page, it's a `GET` type. So laravel will look for a route similar to the one you are visiting.

In this case, you are visiting the url `example.com/my/8`. So laravel will look for a similar route structure. Since you've already defined a route resources, laravel will hit the match `GET /my/{my}`. So the corresponding method will be called.

This won't call `create` or `destroy` methods, because you are just visiting the url (GET). So if you send a request to create a page `POST`, laravel will call the `create` method. Similarly `DELETE` will call `destroy`.

Comment: I don't think this has to be defined Route::get('my/{id}', 'myController@show'); since I have Route::resource('my','myController');

Comment: Yes, you don't have to define it. I was just showing you which route will be executed.

Comment: I see, 'show' is now appearing, but why 'show' and not 'edit' or 'destroy' instead?

Comment: OKay. Sorry. Change your `$id` from show method to `$my`. This will work

Answer (score 1):

If You use route `Route::resource('my','myController');`

This url `http://localhost:8000/my/8` must call action myController@show

Comment: because destroy mast has method DELETE, and update must has method  PUT, and edit has another pattern

Comment: my/{my}/edit  pattern looks strange, why not my/edit/{my}

Comment: That's Laravel developers decision , you can redefine it.